# I want to write wait function until some screen is shown in ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, wait, appium

I am doing android app test automation using Cucumber-Appium in ruby.

I want to write a wait function which should wait till the next page is shown.

I tried few ways but it is not working.

The code:

```
And (/^I wait till '(.*)' appears$/) do |next_page|
    $i=1
    while $i==1 do
    if ObjectSpace.const_get('next_page').new.identity? 
        $current_page = $current_page.change_page('next_page')
        $i=0
    else
    wait_secs(1)
    end
end
```

Can any one suggest something?

Comment: `ObjectSpace.const_get('next_page')` didn't crash?

Comment: Instead of declaring and using a variable, why don't you use `break`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I write a timeout method, I like to pass the block until it times out or resolves to true. Basically, I want it to look like this:

```
timer { ObjectSpace.const_get('NextPage').new.identity? }
```

So my method looks like:

```
def timer(t = 5, &block)
  timeout = Time.now + t
  until Time.now > timeout
    result = yield
    return result if result
    sleep 0.5
  end
  raise "Timer failed after #{t} seconds"
end
```

This method loops over my block until `yield` returns truthy. It will sleep for a half a second and timeout after `t` seconds, which defaults to 5. If you wanted it to return `false` instead of raising an error, you just need to change the last line to `false`.

I'm not familiar enough with appium to write the block to check for your next page, but I imagine it would look similar to my first code example above.